# DPM 2016 System State Protection Windows Server Backup Event 19 2155413599

Tags: backup, windows-server-backup, scdpm, agent

I am using Data Protection Manager 2016 and have configured "System State Backup" on a server. The server has the agent installed, Windows Server Backup feature enabled, and the configured dpm user is in the backup operator group.

The backup keeps failing with meaningless messages in DPM admin console. "Recommended action" leads to same result.

I have tracked down in the eventviewer of the to be backed up server (see also https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc734395(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN )

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Backup" Guid="{1DB28F2E-8F80-4027-8C5A-A11F7F10F62D}" /> 
  <EventID>19</EventID> 
  <Version>3</Version> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x4000000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-05-19T08:27:32.395701700Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>161</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="2760" ThreadID="856" /> 
  <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-Backup</Channel> 
  <Computer>vm</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-11" /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="HRESULT">0x8079005f</Data> 
  <Data Name="BackupTime">2021-05-19T08:27:32.394029700Z</Data> 
  <Data Name="BackupTarget">J:</Data> 
  <Data Name="NumOfVolumes">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="VolumeNames" /> 
  <Data Name="ErrorMessage">%%2155413599</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

I do not know where the faulty "BackupTarget" is coming from, there is no J: drive. From descriptions found on the net, DPM is supposed to backup the system state to the C: drive (that has reasonable amount of free space).

Answer (score 0):

Searching some more, I found a config file which is conveniently and following an age old standard located in the program folder at

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Data Protection Manager\DPM\Datasources\PSDataSourceConfig.xml
```

This file contained a reference to the J: drive (in the  node). Editing it and changing it to C: resolved the issue, the next "synchronization job" succeeded, the state of the system state backup is green now.

On another system, on the C:\ drive, there just wasn't enough space for the backup to succeed.

On yet another system, I had to uninstall/reinstall Windows Server Backup. Afterwards, it tried to backup to H: drive, which also needed to be changed to C: (like above).